# Python Kivy - How to react on multiple key downs?

Tags: python, kivy, keyboard-events, keydown

So I read this SO post:
[How to handle several keys pressed at the same time in Kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586319/how-to-handle-several-keys-pressed-at-the-same-time-in-kivy)

And I implemented the Pong game from the tutorial on the Kivy website (http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html).
My PongGame Widget has the following methods:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(PongGame, self).__init__()
    self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down)
    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up = self._on_keyboard_up)

def _keyboard_closed (self):
    self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
    self._keyboard = None

def _on_keyboard_down (self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    print('### ----------------------------------- ###')
    print('The keys', keycode, 'have been pressed down')
    print('You pressed the key', keycode[1], '.', sep=' ', end='\n')
    #print(' - text is %r' % text)
    print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)

    if keycode[1] == 'w':
        if self.player1.center_y + 20 < self.height-85:
            self.player1.center_y += 20
    elif keycode[1] == 's':
        self.player1.center_y -= 20
    elif keycode[1] == 'up':
        self.player2.center_y += 20
    elif keycode[1] == 'down':
        self.player2.center_y -= 20

    return True
"""
def _on_keyboard_up (self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    print('### ----------------------------------- ###')
    print('The keys', keycode, 'have been released.')
    print('You pressed the key', keycode[1], '.', sep=' ', end='\n')
    #print(' - text is %r' % text)
    print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)

    return True
"""

def _on_keyboard_up(self, *args):
    print('up', args)
```

With this I can control the two players using 'w', 's', 'up' and 'down'. However, only the action for the last pressed button is executed. This is a problem, because the players could disturb each others inputs by pressing buttons all the time, when the other player wants to move their paddle.

How would I implement, to have concurrent controls for both players, so that they can't hinder each other, except when the keyboard can't take any more pressed keys (hardware limit)?

I want to use Kivy for developing a desktop game currently, not for smart phones, so I want to use a real keyboard to control the characters.

Answer (score 3):

My solution very is similar, but it's shorter. 
This is the simple example of using set() as list of active buttons.

So, if you wan't to add another action in my solution you just have to add entry to an self.pressed_actions dict in format 'button_character':lambda function which will run your function with parameters.

This example will promp to the console which buttons are active in every frame.

Feel free to use.

*set is like a list but without repeating. So you don't have to wory about more entries of same button.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Basic(Widget):

    pFrame = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Basic, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)

        self.pressed_keys = set()

        self.pressed_actions = {
            'w': lambda: self.text_example('w pressed'),
            's': lambda: self.text_example('s pressed'),
            'a': lambda: self.text_example('a pressed'),
            'd': lambda: self.text_example('d pressed'),
        }

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        self.pressed_keys.add(keycode[1])

    def _on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        self.pressed_keys.remove(keycode[1])

    def text_example(self, text):
        print('Frame: %s Key %s' % (self.pFrame, text))

    def update(self, dt):
        for key in self.pressed_keys:
            try:
                self.pressed_actions[key]()
            except KeyError:
                print("Frame: %s Key %s. Omitted" % (self.pFrame, key))

        self.pFrame += 1

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):    
        basic = Basic() 
        Clock.schedule_interval(basic.update, 1.0 / 2.0)
        return basic

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        MyApp().run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('App has been closed by ^C')
```

Comment: This solution is better because it overcomes the "lag" that's apparent in the original Pong example.  Anyone who has played the demo understands that the first key press lags, then subsequently, the paddle will move.  This solution obtains silky movement.  Thanks @Vermibus!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution now, but I don't know if this is the best we can have.
The following is the complete code of the pong application, which enables the players to independently move their paddles.

```
from random import randint
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock


class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)


    def bounce_ball (self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)


    def move (self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    pressed_keys = {
        'w': False,
        's': False,
        'up': False,
        'down': False
    }


    def __init__(self):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__()
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up = self._on_keyboard_up)


    def _keyboard_closed (self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None


    def _on_keyboard_down (self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        #pressed_key = self._keyboard.keycode_to_string(keycode) # this does not work somehow
        pressed_key = keycode[1]
        print('You pressed the key', pressed_key, '.', sep=' ', end='\n')

        self.pressed_keys[pressed_key] = True

        return True


    def _on_keyboard_up (self, keyboard, keycode):
        released_key = keycode[1]
        print('You released the key', released_key, '.', sep=' ', end='\n')
        self.pressed_keys[released_key] = False
        return True


    def serve_ball (self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(vel).rotate(randint(0, 360))


    def update (self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        # bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        # bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        # went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))

        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

        # actions for keys pressed
        if self.pressed_keys['w']:
            if self.player1.center_y + 20 < self.height:
                self.player1.center_y += 20

        if self.pressed_keys['s']:
            if self.player1.center_y + 20 > 0:
                self.player1.center_y -= 20

        if self.pressed_keys['up']:
            if self.player2.center_y + 20 < self.height:
                self.player2.center_y += 20

        if self.pressed_keys['down']:
            if self.player2.center_y + 20 > 0:
                self.player2.center_y -= 20


    def on_touch_move (self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y


class PongApp(App):
    def build (self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

If you know a better way, or a more Kivy-like way of doing this, please post an answer : )