# Multiple (three or more) keypresses in Kivy/Python do not create events

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, keyboard-events

I am not very advanced as a programmer and I'm trying to build an app in Kivy, and I ran into something I can't explain (on Mac OS X). Running this program from an answer from [How to handle several keys pressed at the same time in Kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586319/how-to-handle-several-keys-pressed-at-the-same-time-in-kivy), for example, press and hold `h` and `spacebar` both, and then press `j`, `k`, `l`, or `'` does not create keyup or keydown events. However, `;` does. Also press and hold `j` and `f` and press `v` and `m` do not create events, but all the other keys on the bottom row do. There are other examples as well. I have not been able to find a reference to explain this. From experimenting I am guessing that on my system there is a maximum of six keys that can be pressed and held at once with all of them creating events, but it's not consistent nor do I know why there is an upper limit. Can anyone explain this? And does anyone know how to make the keyboard work as advertised, so that in Kivy keyboard events are created no matter how many keys are pressed in whatsoever order?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up = self._on_keyboard_up)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, *args):
        print('down', args)

    def _on_keyboard_up(self, *args):
        print('up', args)


    def build(self):
        self.moveable = Scatter()
        self.moveable.add_widget( Label(text = 'Hello moving world!') )
        return self.moveable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```